# why can't you pass parameters directly using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

I understand that you can't pass any parameters to `addEventListener`. You have to do this

```
el.addEventListener("click", function(){callSomeFunction("myString");}, false);
```

But what is the reason for making us do it in this way?

Comment: If you're asking why you can't specify additional arguments like with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, it's probably because the listener is already receiving an `event` argument. How would it behave if you were specifying your own arguments?

Comment: Could you please provide an example how you'd want to bind the event handler with additional arguments?

Comment: @FelixKling el.addEventListener("click", myFunc(1,2,3), false);

Comment: @thomas `el.addEventListener("click", myFunc.bind(el,1,2,3), false);`

Comment: @Ian I've never seen this before. Thanks.

Comment: @thomas: This has nothing to do with `addEventListener` in particular. Whenever you do `foo(bar())` you are executing `bar` first and then pass the return value to `foo`. In case of `addEventListener` you have to pass a function though, not call the function.

Comment: @Ian `bind` is generally a good option, but it is appropriate for the specific case of event listeners?  Is it possible to `bind` second, third, and fourth arguments without overriding the first event argument? (Note the OP isn't even using the first argument here, so `bind` is absolutely fine here, but it's a concern in the general bound-event-listener case.)

Comment: @apsillers That's a great point, I didn't even think of that. I'm so used to suggesting it for `setTimeout`, that I forgot about the `event` being passed (even though it's been mentioned in comments elsewhere). I guess I'm not sure what happens if you use `.bind()` in this scenario, and I'm pretty sure you **can't** use it if you want to access the `event` object. I'm gonna go try some things out

Comment: @Ian: In that case (and in your example), the event object would be passed as fourth argument. Quick example: `var a = function() { console.log(arguments); }.bind(null, 1); a(2);` (shows `[1,2]`).

Comment: @FelixKling Really? Interesting.

Comment: @apsillers In case you didn't see his comment, FelixCling pointed out the event gets passed as an additional argument on the end. So I guess it's still okay to use for event handlers, but doesn't follow the convention where the `event` object is the first param. Here's the example I was messing around with: http://jsfiddle.net/pnu88/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because if you did this:

```
el.addEventListener("click", callSomeFunction("myString"), false);
```

It would execute `callSomeFunction` immediately, and then return its value to `addEventListener` which is then used.

For example, if I had this:

```
function callSomeFunction() {
  doSomeThings();
  return 10;
}
```

Then `el.addEventListener("click", callSomeFunction("myString"), false);` would actually call `el.addEventListener("click", 10, false);`.

If you have a function with no arguments, you could pass it directly:

```
el.addEventListener("click", callSomeFunction, false);
```

Comment: Maybe the OP meant something like `.addEventListener("click", callSomeFunction, false, "myString");` though.

Comment: @FelixKling Is that even valid JS? I am pretty sure `addEventListener` only takes 3 arguments, but I may be mistaken

Comment: Syntactically yes. Of course it does not work because `addEventListener` does not work like this. But that's how I understood the question: Why can't you pass additional arguments to `addEventListener` for the event handler. I think OP has clarify their question a bit more. (I am not saying your answer is wrong or anything like that, I, for myself, just need a bit more clarity).

Comment: @FelixKling Oh ok, for a second I thought that would call `callSomeFunction("myString")`

Comment: @Doorknob It's valid, but no, it's not "correct" -- the OP's question is *why* he can't do something like that (and/or how he could somehow achieve that effect).

Comment: @FelixKling my question is more like, what is the practical advantage of having a function be called in this way, when it's not normally how functions are treated. If that makes sense...

Comment: @thomas: How do you think functions are usually treated?

Comment: @FelixKling by being able to pass them as many parameters as you/the function wants

Comment: @thomas If you do `callSomeFunction("myString")` it will call the function immediately, which is perfectly normal

Comment: @thomas: Maybe what confuses you is that fact that the function you pass to `addEventListener` is not called by *you*. It is called by the engine when the event occurs, and the way the function is called only passes one argument to it, the event object. You cannot influence this because you don't control the code. This is always the case whenever you use external/native libraries/interfaces.

Comment: @FelixKling can you give another example?

Comment: @FelixKling and then why does it work with the simple addition of `function theFunction("string1", "string2", false")`?

Comment: @thomas: You mean `function() { theFunction("string1", "string2", false"); }`? Because in that case `function() { ... }` is a function expression which creates a new function object. It does not call the function, it **defines** a function. I will just repeat my example from the other comment here: If you have `foo(bar())` then `bar` is executed first and the return value is passed to `foo`. That's how argument resolution works and it is no different for `addEventListener`. Also, if `foo` expected a *function reference* (i.e. `foo(bar)`), then you don't have control how `foo` calls `bar`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, that's what I meant. Okay. I think it's becoming clearer.

Comment: @FelixKling Okay, this is from ages ago, but I'm curious if you think that this (based on the answer below) is a good practice/typical way of attaching an a function that takes arguments to a click event? http://jsbin.com/sexelipu/1/edit

Comment: Are there other JS methods that operate this way? I'm pretty basic level JS, so I wouldn't know. Just curious if this is common.

Answer (score 3):

`addEventListener` must take a function object as its second argument, but there's no reason why that function object could not be produced by *another function*. Perhaps you'd be interested in a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that generates functions:

```
function generateAlertFunc(alertString) {
    return function() {
        alert(alertString);
    }
}

el.addEventListener("click", generateAlertFunc("myString"), false);
```

`generateAlertFunc` takes arguments and uses them to build a new function which is passed into `addEventListener`.

Comment: okay. So I guess I was mistaken. I thought that you could not do this.

Comment: @thomas Of course you can - the point is the `addEventListener` requires a function reference for its second parameter. Calling the `generateAlertFunc` returns a **function**, so it works correctly

Comment: @thomas Yeah the same with `setTimeout` - it expects a function reference, so you can take this same approach, or use `.bind()` like you just saw

Comment: @thomas Functions are just objects. Any function that accepts a callback (`setTimeout`, `addEventListener`, etc.) is expecting a function object. You can generate and refer to that function object however you like (e.g., as the return value of another function, as an anonymous literal, stored in a variable, etc.).

Comment: Interesting solution. And in other calls that are not `addEventListener`, `generateAlertFunc(alertString)` would still work.